# How to remove the middle part of text dynamically, when the middle is of different lengths?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here's an example:

Extension: 12345678 - Random, Name

That line exists in multiple places in the workbook, and I need to format it to leave only the extension number itself. However, extensions are different lengths. I need a formula driven solution. Thanks!

Comment: is the word 'Random' is where the extension number place is in the text ?

Comment: and is the 'Random' always in between the character `-` and `,` ? if yes, it will be easy.

Answer (score 0):

here you go...

[image]

```
=TRIM(MID(A1,SEARCH("-",A1)+1,SEARCH(",",A1)-SEARCH("-",A1)-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work as well:

```
=REPLACE(A1, 1, LEN(A1), MID(A1, SEARCH("-", A1)+1, SEARCH(",",A1)-1-SEARCH("-",A1)))
```

Example:

[image]

The same result as the answer with `TRIM` but using `REPLACE` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the other solutions depend on some character to be found such as a hyphen of a comma or something else. If this cannot be ensured then the following function might be better suited.

```
=MID(A1,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789")),MAX(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},"0123456789"&A1))-1)
```

Yet, here is also a pitfall. This one assumes that there is only **one** number in that cell. So, if you should ever come across something like this:

> Extension: 12345678 - Random, Name 1234567

Then the above function will not work.